# How to use askopenfilename for .exe files?

Tags: windows, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a program with a GUI where you can search for Files.
I use the `askopenfilename` from Tkinter.

```
root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

After I built it into a .exe file with pyinstaller, I wanted to start it.
But if I start the `.exe` file, I see a window for a short while and then it closes instantly. 
It helped not to use `root.mainloop`. 
What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with `askopenfilename`. It seems like that line of code is working just fine. It sounds like you're asking how to run a .exe program from python. Does this .exe create its own windows? How are you starting it? Are you checking the return code after it exits? These are all details we need to know.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's mostly a "This works in my environment, but when I make a `PyInstaller` .exe it doesn't" question. I've tried it as a `--onefile` with and without terminal, it's either a bad import, or a broken setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely an issue in the imports, you didn't include any so all I can do is assume.

This is what I usually would use:

(Tested working on python 3.8.1 x64, pyinstaller 3.6)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                            title = "Select file",
                                            filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

Made the .exe with `pyinstaller.exe --onefile "path/to/script.py"`